# Getting Count(*) vs Actual Data has performance implications

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-performance, full-text-indexing

I can't make sense of the following two queries.  First one only gets the count of the entire resultset.

Second one gets the actual data , but limit the resultset to 10 rows.

- Somehow the first one can't use index. I have tried to use `USE INDEX (`timestamp_index`,`Fulltext_title`,`Fulltext_description`)` with no avail.
- The count query does not need an order by , but I just tried to see if it can use index that way.
- As far as I can see the WHERE clause is the same, which to my knowledge is the biggest factor in selecting the index.

### GET THE COUNT

```
SELECT count(*) as total FROM table1 
WHERE 1=1
AND type in ('category1','category3','category2') 
AND ( 
    MATCH(title) AGAINST (' +"apple"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    OR 
    MATCH(description) AGAINST (' +"apple"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    )
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
;
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|   798 |
+-------+
1 row in set (3.75 sec)
```

### EXPLAIN EXTENDED

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref      | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1   | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 669689 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

### Get the Actual Result

```
SELECT id, title,desciption,timestamp  FROM table1
WHERE 1=1
AND type in ('category1','category3','category2') 
AND ( 
    MATCH(title) AGAINST (' +"apple"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    OR 
    MATCH(description) AGAINST (' +"apple"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    )
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 0, 10 ;
```

10 rows in set (0.06 sec)

### EXPLAIN EXTENDED

```
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref      | rows | filtered   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+----   --+------+------------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1 index | NULL          | timestamp_index   | 21          | NULL |   10 | 6696890.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: `limit` has very strong influence on optimizers, I'm not sure where you're going with this question - the two queries are completely different.

Comment: The limit will make it run a great deal faster. The Count(*) has to do a full table scan, especially if it's run for the first time. It may increase performance on subsequent calls.

Comment: ok ... let me rephrase .. How can I make the first query use an index .. perhaps like the one using in the second query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer ... I combined the two indexes. So we don't have to have a full table scan just because we are doing a count(*)

```
SELECT count(*) as total FROM table1 WHERE 1=1
    AND type in ('category1','category2','category3') 
    AND MATCH(title, description) AGAINST (' +"apple"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  
;

+----+-------------+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type     | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref  | rows | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table1   | fulltext | FT_title_description | FT_title_description | 0       | NULL |    1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------+----------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+------+------+----------+-------------+
+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|   798 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.83 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

On second query. You want first 10 elements. So optimizer use timestamp index, sort the table and keep checking rows until found 10 element matching your `WHERE`

On your first query, the db has to scan the whole db to find what element match your query, so your `ORDER BY` doesnt help because you want count the total number of rows matching yor where.

Now also depend on how you define your index. Do you have one Index for `Type`,  `Title` and `Description` ? Do you have compisite Index?

Check this  one  MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)